# CakePHP 1.3: How we can send email with 2 or more (file) attachments in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, email-attachments

I want to send some image files via CakePHP mail.

Currently I am using `$this->Email->attachments = array($Path.$fileName);` for one file only
I want to send multiple files in one email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works just like described in the manual, simply add more paths to the array.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1638/Attachments

```
$this->Email->attachments = array(
    $Path . $fileName,
    $Path . $someOtherFile
);
```

Comment: Tanks a lot. for your ref. i used 
`code` 
$this->Email->attachments= array($this->data['form']['file0']['name']=>$this->data['form']['file0']['tmp_name'],$this->data['form']['file1']['name']=>$this->data['form']['file1']['tmp_name']);
`code`

thanks